# Spring Security - Get user details from another table

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Sprin Security to get the user details but I don't know how to get the **firstname** based on the following graphic.

[image]

**Getting the username.**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index(Model model){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = auth.getName(); // Get the username
    model.addAttribute("username", username);
    return "index";
}
```

**Getting the role authority**

```
<span sec:authentication="principal.authorities"></span>
```

Is there any way to get values from another table?

Comment: How have you setup the relationship between the Data and Person table?

Comment: @Aeseir I have updated the answer, It has cardinality now.

Comment: Have a look at my answer, that is what you need to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to do a bit more research for solutions around this but here is my high level advice on how to accomplish this:

Database Schema:
You need to create a foreign key link between Data and Person tables and have one of them store the relationship. e.g. in Person table have data_id column that points to Data table's ID column.

Spring MVC:
Once you create the foreign key link you would need to implement this line in each of your entity classes:

```
public class Data {
// your existing stuff
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn("person_id")
private Person person;
// getters and setters
}

public class Person {
// your existing stuff
@OneToOne
private Data data;
// getters and setters
}
```

Then your Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String index(Model model){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String username = auth.getName(); // Get the username
// here you connect to your database and pull out the relevant entity object
Data data = dbDAO.findByUsername(username);
// now pull the person object and allocate it to a new object
Person person = data.getPerson();
// do your transformations or queries on the person object
// or
// pass it to your view layer via
model.addAttribute("person", person);
    model.addAttribute("username", username);
    return "index";
}
```

This is one way you can achieve your goal of getting the person and data objects that correlate and then further operate on them,

Comment: Hi, Can you give me a hand with this little problem? Thanks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31487108/spring-mvc-setting-values-by-default-in-controllers

Answer (score 0):

There is no link between Data table(used as login for spring in your case) and person table so you cant even do an sql query on Person table to get the firstname.

You need a foreign key that will link both the person table and the data table.You can for example add a username or usernameid column to the person table and have this be a foreign key to the data table linked to username so that you can query the database using the string returned when you use auth.getname().

Answer (score 0):

You may implement custom [UserDetailsService](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html) and use [authentication.getDetails()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.html%23getDetails())